# Array of Structs in Python

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, mmap

I cannot use multiprocessing, I need shared memory among entirely separate python processes on Windows using python 3. I've figured out how to do this using mmap, and it works great...when I use simple primitive types. However, I need to pass around more complex information. I've found the ctypes.Structure and it seems to be exactly what I need.

I want to create an array of ctypes.Structure and update an individual element within that array, write it back to memory as well as read an individual element.

```
import ctypes
import mmap


class Person(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('name', ctypes.c_wchar * 10),
        ('age', ctypes.c_int)
    ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_people = 5

    person = Person()

    people = Person * num_people
    mm_file = mmap.mmap(-1, ctypes.sizeof(people), access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE,     tagname="shmem")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `people` is not an array yet, it's still a class. In order to have your array, you need to initialize the class using `from_buffer()`, just like you were doing before with `c_int`:

```
PeopleArray = Person * num_people
mm_file = mmap.mmap(-1, ctypes.sizeof(PeopleArray), ...)
people = PeopleArray.from_buffer(mm_file)

people[0].name = 'foo'
people[0].age = 27
people[1].name = 'bar'
people[1].age = 42
...
```

Comment: interestingly...it doesn't want bytes, it wants a unicode string.  So this works if you remove the b from in front of those string literals.

Comment: I can't upvote you due to lack of rep but answer was accepted.